# how to make Typescript generics be possble undefined and this.$refs is not type of HTMLElement

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, echarts

I am newbie in Typescript.
I defined echarts as following

```
 const echartsModule = inject<typeof echarts>("echarts");
```

when I try to use the echartsModule, it shows two errors.

1. Object is possibly 'undefined'. (echartsModule)
2. Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HTMLElement'. (this.$refs.theChart)

```
let myChart = this.echartsModule.init(this.$refs.theChart, null, {
        renderer: "svg",
      });
```

Do u know how to make echartsModule be possible with undefined?

this.$refs.theChart is HTMLElement from my opinion. why it shows this error
Thank you